# Android studio AVD manager cannot open any instance of any virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am getting this error when starting any android emulator with any system image.
I run the emulator, the bar reaches like 20% and returns this error.
No matter what virtual device I create and what system image I install, it always throw this error. Uninstalled and reinstalled, reboot pc, nothing works.
[image]

Comment: Upgrade the Android Emulator to the latest version.

Comment: it is the latest because the android installation is brand new

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first check if the images are properly configured or not. If they are, but the problem persists, then follow the below :

There can be multiple possibilities for such kind of error:

## Less memory

The AVD has its own storage, that is simply using the system's storage. So check whether the disk space is enough to accommodate the minimum storage requirements of the AVD.

**Solution** : Clean up the storage space.

## Wrong SDK Path

Many a times, a user may have more than one SDK installations on their machine and the environment variable points to some other location. Causing the AVD termination.

**Solution:** Find the path of the proper SDK installation and update the environment variables and restart the system.

## Old Version of Android Emulator

The current version of the emulator might not be updated.

**Solution** : Update the Android Emulator to latest version.

Steps:-

1. Go to Tools
2. SDK Manager
3. Android SDK
4. SDK Tools
5. Update Android Emulator

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest sdks in sdk manager and also make sure the latest version of HAXM for Intel and Hypervisor Driver for AMD processors is installed.

If you already have installed one of them, try to reinstall, either via sdk manager or manually.